# Matching data

Tags: mysql

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

I have this table hospital

Nurse  | Ward      | Doctor
A001   |  W2       | DR1
A001   |  W2       | DR2
F002   |  W2       | DR1
F005   |  W2       | DR1
F005   |  W2       | DR2
J003   |  W4       | DR5

What I am trying to do is display what Nurse on Ward 2 works with
Doctor 1 but not Doctor 2

The answer I'm tring to get is F002 | W2  as she works on ward 2 with doctor 1 but
not doctor 2.

I've tried for ages to get this to work - any help would be brill.

There are no NULL entries in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unclear if you want to

1. exclude Nurses that work with Doctor
   2 on other wards, or
2. exclude nurses only if they work with Doctor 2 on Ward 2,

If the former:

```
   Select Nurse From Table T
   Where Ward = 'W2'
      And Doctor = 'DR1'
      And Not Exists (Select * From Table
                      Where Nurse = T.Nurse
                          And Doctor = 'DR2')
```

if the latter,

```
   Select Nurse From Table T
   Where Ward = 'W2'
      And Doctor = 'DR1'
      And Not Exists (Select * From Table
                      Where Nurse = T.Nurse
                          And Ward = 'W2'
                          And Doctor = 'DR2')
```